# Create Grafana Plugin Failed - Never include this file directly <lzma.h>

Tags: node.js, homebrew, grafana

I am having trouble building a Grafana plugin, when I run:

`npx @grafana/toolkit plugin:create testPlugin1`

I get the error:

````
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:9:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:43:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFBase.h:72:
/usr/local/include/Block.h:16:3: error: Never include this file directly. Use <lzma.h> instead.
#       error Never include this file directly. Use <lzma.h> instead.
        ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:93:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_check'
        lzma_check check;
        ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:148:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_vli'
        lzma_vli compressed_size;
        ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:172:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_vli'
        lzma_vli uncompressed_size;
        ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:200:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_filter'
        lzma_filter *filters;
        ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:217:20: error: use of undeclared identifier 'LZMA_CHECK_SIZE_MAX'
        uint8_t raw_check[LZMA_CHECK_SIZE_MAX];
                          ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:231:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_vli'
        lzma_vli reserved_int3;
        ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:232:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_vli'
        lzma_vli reserved_int4;
        ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:233:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_vli'
        lzma_vli reserved_int5;
        ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:234:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_vli'
        lzma_vli reserved_int6;
        ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:235:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_vli'
        lzma_vli reserved_int7;
        ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:236:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_vli'
        lzma_vli reserved_int8;
        ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:237:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_reserved_enum'
        lzma_reserved_enum reserved_enum1;
        ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:238:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_reserved_enum'
        lzma_reserved_enum reserved_enum2;
        ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:239:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_reserved_enum'
        lzma_reserved_enum reserved_enum3;
        ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:240:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_reserved_enum'
        lzma_reserved_enum reserved_enum4;
        ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:261:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_bool'
        lzma_bool ignore_check;
        ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:263:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_bool'
        lzma_bool reserved_bool2;
        ^
/usr/local/include/Block.h:264:2: error: unknown type name 'lzma_bool'
        lzma_bool reserved_bool3;
        ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/tempjones/.npm/_npx/99304/lib/node_modules/@grafana/toolkit/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v8.16.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
Unexpected token {```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and found that if I ran:

`brew doctor`

I had some warnings:

```
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
  /usr/local/include/check.h
  /usr/local/include/container.h
  /usr/local/include/delta.h
  /usr/local/include/filter.h
  /usr/local/include/hardware.h
  /usr/local/include/index.h
  /usr/local/include/index_hash.h
  /usr/local/include/lzma12.h
  /usr/local/include/stream_flags.h
  /usr/local/include/version.h
  /usr/local/include/vli.h
```

Deleting these files, including `lzma12.h` seemed to fix the problem.